# Can't upload Arduino sketch in macOS Catalina, sync error but serial works

Tags: arduino, upload

I'm trying to update a sketch I last uploaded years ago and on a different computer.
Arduino compiles ok, and my old Arduino Nano code communicates to serial monitor just fine, but when I try to upload the edited sketch, I get:

```
>Arduino: 1.8.13 (Mac OS X), Board: "Arduino Nano, ATmega328P"
>
>Sketch uses 13404 bytes (43%) of program storage space. Maximum is 30720 bytes.
>Global variables use 601 bytes (29%) of dynamic memory, leaving 1447 bytes for local variables. >Maximum is 2048 bytes.
>/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude ->C/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p ->carduino -P/dev/cu.usbserial-1440 -b115200 -D ->Uflash:w:/var/folders/w4/ljrzz3sx7b9blnrqwn12yssm0000gn/T/arduino_build_133738/Front_v4_FLLlock>_newTenant.ino.hex:i 
>
>avrdude: Version 6.3-20190619
>         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
>         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch
>
>         System wide configuration file is >"/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"
>         User configuration file is "/Users/dbg/.avrduderc"
>
>         Using Port                    : /dev/cu.usbserial-1440
>         Using Programmer              : arduino
>         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
>avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x0d
>avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x0a
>avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x0d
>avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x0a
>avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x44
>avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x69
>avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x67
>avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x69
>avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x74
>avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x61
>
>avrdude done.  Thank you.
>
>An error occurred while uploading the sketch
>
>
>This report would have more information with
>"Show verbose output during compilation"
>option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

At first, it failed with a message that the user configuration file did not exist, so I created an empty one with BBEdit and saved it, figuring that Arduino would put some contents into it as needed. That error message went away, but the behavior did not otherwise change.

The old code listens for serial characters and produces output, and that mechanism works fine, so the problem is not just the serial driver. This is a cheap Arduino Nano, so I recall in previous lives I used to get CH340 driver missing problems, but that can't be the problem this time.

I haven't programmed this nano for several years, and meanwhile I've changed my MacBook Pro and upgraded to Catalina, so subtle things are possible.

Any suggestions what to try next? I need to change the door lock combo inside the sketch, for a new tenant.

Comment: Are you using an Arduino and some old code to run a door lock for a paying tenant? If so, that might be a risk - at the very least I would want to see this under continuous integration, so live issues can be handled quickly. You need to automatically run your build every day to ensure it remains in a buildable state. Furthermore, if you are writing the software itself, I'd wager it hasn't been through a security audit. Manufacturers of hotel keycard locks do much the same thing, and they've been found to be easy to hack.

Comment: The first thing I'd do is to take the advice in the error: use the "Show verbose output during compilation" option.

Comment: When you got this working before, did you use a Arduino Nano, or was it some other kind of Arduino? Use the same one as your last successful build if you can.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had to choose the processor ATmega328P (with old boot loader). Once I did that, all worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved if you are using a 64-bit Mac version of the Arduino IDE which you can download on the Arduino website. The "usual" Arduino IDE is 32-bit.  32-bit apps are not supported in Catalina.  But, unfortunately, the developers of the 64-bit Mac version neglected to include a file/function which is a part of Xcode. That gets a BIG BOOOOO! Sooooo, you have to download Xcode (from the Mac app store) and install it.  This is what developers use to create apps on Apple's app store.  It's version 11.4.1, and arrives as an XIP file 7.6GB...!  Uggggg.  Click on it to open and install.  Migrate the Xcode app to Finder.  Dont be put off when it takes about as long to install Xcode as it did to download. No need to download other Xcode auxiliary apps as you wont be using Xcode to do anything. The Mac 64-bit version for the Arduino IDE should now work. Mine does.